# Pimcore document snippet only displaying "Hello World"

Tags: php, zend-framework, pimcore

I've created a snippet for a contact sidebar.

1. Created Documenttype with Template snippets/contact.php
2. Created SnippetsController with action contactAction
3. Created view/snippets/contact.php Template with code
4. Added Snippet to page in the Backend "new Snippet" -> contact snippet -> name = "contact"
5. Added snippet("contact"); ?> to Template of Page
6. Clicked on page editing and dropped the snippet in position
7. Preview and editing only dispays "Hello world"

Why is my code in /snippets/contact.php not loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it's not enough to set "Template => snippets/contact.php".

It still uses the default controller. You have to set "Controller" to "Snippet" and "Action" to "Contact" to get it working.